# Quickly detect via MAC if entities are present on a network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping, arp

Is there a fast and reliable way to use a device's MAC address to determine if it is currently connected to a network from a Windows PC/Server? If not, then from an Ubuntu server?

- arp -a doesn't work on its own as the items stay in the cache too long.
- arp -a combined with clearing the cache every 5 minutes might work, but seems inefficient, and only works if the cache entirely repopulates within 5 minutes. Would it?

Background:
I got tired of clocking in at work, and so I wrote a quick app which run as a windows service, checks if my phone is present on the company network periodically, logs that to a database, and then hosts a website which allows you to view when I was in the office by summing the data over a given range (amazing what you can do with the right libraries in a few hours).

It took about a week before the company decided they'd like everyone to use the app in place of our time-clock system where possible.

Originally I was using a DHCP reservation and periodically pinging my Android phone to detect it. When expanding, however, I quickly ran into the issue that iPhones don't respond to pings. Aside from that, pings are slow. It takes about a second per phone to reliably confirm via ping that it's there.

I tried running arp -a and combing through the result for MAC matches, but items stay in the arp cache practically indefinitely. I've considered reading the cache, then flushing it after, but I don't know if it will reliably repopulate in time. That's a potential solution if it does, though I don't like the idea of flushing the arp cache every five minutes.

My current solution is to do an SNMP poll on our access points to gather their connected clients, and then parse that to see if I can find MAC matches. It's fast, and it's reliable, but it's very specific to the access points in question. If we switch out the access points, then the next ones might not list their connected clients via SNMP. Even if they do, I'll need to reconfigure the snmp polls.

I'm thinking that if there's a known port which accepts connections on any given phone, I could open a tcp connection to that and then close it in place of a ping, but I feel that there must be a fast layer 2 solution here somewhere.

Comment: We use an app called [Simple In/Out](https://www.simpleinout.com/) which does a similar thing to what you are trying to develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `arp`. Use `arping`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping

> Arping is a computer software tool for discovering and probing hosts on a computer network. Arping probes hosts on the attached network link by sending Link Layer frames using the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) request method addressed to a host identified by its MAC address of the network interface.
>
> The utility program may use ARP to resolve an IP address provided by the user.
>   The function of arping is analogous to the utility ping for probing the network with the Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) at the Internet Layer of the Internet Protocol Suite.

It's basically what `arp` does but without the whole OS ARP caching business, i.e. just does sends literal, one-off arp requests on the wire.

P.S. Remember this whole ARP business will only work on a single local subnet, if you need wider reach you'll have to run it on the router(s).

P.P.S. You could just use short DHCP leases (e.g. 1 minute to 5 minutes). Granted, Apple devices are known for disobeying DHCP spec in the past, but that shouldn't be as bad these days. I hope.

P.P.P.S. Even `arping` won't be 100% reliable (though it should be upwards of 99%). Some devices ignore unsolicited inbound arp requests just like some devices ignore pings. Yes, it violates IETF, but so does ignoring pings...

Woof.

Comment: For the moment, I think I'm going to stick with SNMP. I think yours is the most valid solution though. If SNMP fails me at some point, I can write a Linux service which hosts an HTTP api for remotely performing arping. I could then deploy that to an RPI/BeagleBoard or something similar, have one of those on each subnet, and then have the primary service poll those, knowing ahead of time what their IP address is. That would scale into a system that could cover multiple subnets and reliably find all compliant devices.

Comment: I could also use tcpdump to figure out what arping is sending and then use WinPCap to inject that onto all available interfaces. Similar to what That Brazilian Gato suggested I do with Fing.

Answer (score 0):

You were correct in using ARP. Because you don't want to rely on the device telling you its on the network which is another way, you could do it yourself. ARP can facilitate that, and not only will it give you the mac address but it gives you the ip address they are using on the network as well. When you clear the arpcache, it will repopulate as needed. Meaning, it will only populate the cache with the addresses it has had to communicate with on the network.

A better solution, if you are going to know the mac addresses of the clients already, you could assign them static ip addresses in the network. This will solve your caching problem to an extent as the cache does periodically become stale. Which means the next time your network interface has to communicate with the device, it will do another lookup. Now, since you have the problem with Apple devices not pinging back, was going to suggest, you can always ping your networks broadcast. so for example, if your gateway is 192.168.1.1, the broadcast is 192.168.1.255 and if you sent a ping to that, all devices that accept pings will respond to you.

So to re-cap, you can just keep clearing the arp cache as it will reliably repopulate as its needed for the TCP/IP protocol for the exchanging of packets betweent computers and routers etc. however it will just put a load on your network interface. Or in the app, have it detect when it connects to the company network and send a ping to your server on a different port than default icmp, have your server listen for said pings, and you can document everything you need. Or just have the app ping your server every so often. Just because the device doesn't accept pings, doesn't mean it can't send one.

Comment: To clarify, there is nothing installed on any of the phones. I'd like to do this entirely server side. That said,  I think sending out a udp broadcast packet after clearing the cache might help it to repopulate. I'm going to leave the question open for a bit to see if there are other ideas in addition to yours.

Comment: Well, not sure what you are allowed to do, but since you got some devices that won't respond back to you via ICMP. What you could do is, if you know the network ip block range the network hands out that everyone is connecting on. Then what you could do, is clear the cache and use methods to scan the ip range to detect if that ip is alive, if it is, you can get the mac address from the device via arp commands on the ip address. This will remove the need to clear your cache. Also this would be more easier, if the network connected through your server and server being connected to the gateway.

Comment: in this way, no device could actually hide from your server and you can obtain all the mac addresses of the devices connected to the network at any time you want

Answer (score 0):

There's an Android app called Fing that basically scans and displays info (including IPs and MACs) about all devices on a network.

I don't know which protocols it uses, but it detect Apple devices. You could use something as Wireshark to try to reverse engineer the app, and use the same technique on your tool. (Someone already tried it [on a related Stack Exchange site](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/19846/1801))

Comment: Apple has their own mDNS/Bonjour? service IIRC. Though I regularly use Fing and AFAIK it just does a brute force arp scan